# Writing successful bash scripts

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script

```
aws s3 sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/

if [[ ! $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "Unable to copy from test bucket"
   exit 1
fi
```

Is that the right way to run a command and check its return value?

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work, but any good shell script declares what shell should interpret it. You should add a first line of your script (no spaces at the left margin)

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(Or whatever is the correct path to bash in your environment). 99% that it is `/bin/bash`.

Your test is a slightly baroque, there is an `-ne` operator that you could use, i.e.

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then 
   . . .
```

Or you can go advanced, and let `if` directly test the return code from you `aws` command, i.e.

```
if ! aws sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/ ; then
  echo "Unable to copy from test bucket"
   exit 1
fi
```

In this case,  you need the `!` to have block execute.

You could even capture any output so you can review error msgs etc with

```
if ! aws sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/ > /tmp/aws_launchlog.txt 2>&1 ; then
  echo "Unable to copy from test bucket"
   exit 1
fi
```

IHTH

Answer (score 3):

Unlike most other languages, in shells like bash the `if` statement is followed by a *command*, the brackets are fooling you.  `[[` is actually a shell keyword (as is `!`), a development of `[` which is a shell built-in, also known as the `test` command.

Use `[[` when you wish to do *pattern matching*, use `((` when you wish to do arithmetic comparisons.

```
if (( some_variable > 0 ))
then
    ...
fi
```

If you just want to test if a command worked (returned zero) then any form of brackets are superfluous.

```
if ! aws s3 sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/
then
    # Always send error messages to stderr
    echo "Unable to copy from test bucket" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Having said that, there are thousands of scripts out there in the wild that do what you have done, and they still work.  Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Your way will work. A simpler way is to put the command directly in the `if`:

```
if ! aws s3 sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/
then
    echo "Unable to copy from test bucket"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

bash's `set -e` is quite useful in these cases.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
aws s3 sync s3://test/ s3://test-li/
# if `aws` returns non-zero, the following code will not be executed

echo 'it succeeded!'
```